# Goldstone boson in Higgs Mechanism

Tags: quantum-field-theory, mass, higgs, symmetry-breaking, goldstone-mode

On P&S's QFT book, page 693, the book discussed "Systematics of the Higgs Mechanism". For the kinetic part of Lagrangian,
$$ \frac{1}{2}\left(D_\mu \phi_i\right)^2=\frac{1}{2}\left(\partial_\mu \phi_i\right)^2+g A_\mu^a\left(\partial_\mu \phi_i T_{i j}^a \phi_j\right)+\frac{1}{2} g^2 A_\mu^a A^{b \mu}\left(T^a \phi\right)_i\left(T^b \phi\right)_i \tag{20.15}$$
if $\phi_i$ acquire vacuum expectation values of $\left\langle\phi_i\right\rangle=\left(\phi_0\right)_i$, we can obtain the gauge boson mass term through the last term of (20.15).
$$\Delta \mathcal{L}=\frac{1}{2} m_{a b}^2 A_\mu^a A^{b \mu} \ \ \ \ m_{a b}^2=g^2\left(T^a \phi_0\right)_i\left(T^b \phi_0\right)_i\tag{20.17 & 18} $$
Also, their have a term after symmetry breaking:
$$\Delta \mathcal{L}=g A_\mu^a \partial_\mu \phi_i\left(T^a \phi_0\right)_i . \tag{20.19} $$
(20.19) is related with explaining gauge boson mass.
P&S write in page 691 that:

> a gauge boson cannot obtain a mass, unless this mass term is associated with a pole in the vacuum polarization amplitude.

Using (20.19) we can derive the Feynman rules for gauge field and goldstone boson scattering, like in (20.20)
[image]
And then we can obtain the vacuum polarization in following form:
[image]

Here comes my question:

1. in the paragraph following (20.19), the book said: "the interaction term does not involve all of the components of $\phi$, only those that are parallel to a vector $T^a \phi_0$ for some choice of $T^a$. These vectors represent the infinitesimal rotations of the vacuum; thus the components $\phi_i$ that appear in (20.19) are precisely the Goldstone bosons." Why $\phi_i$ can be Goldstone bosons? I am really troubled for the book's description；
2. in (20.21), the book give the vacuum polarization form, now there have a pole ($k=0$), and what's the meaning of "transverse" of this diagram? As I remember in chapter 7's description, this vacuum diagram don't have pole at $q=0$;
3. Also, in eq.(20.20), their have a relative minus sign between $k^{\mu}$ and $k^{\nu}$, I thought the reason is for partial derivate act on in and out particle have a sign difference.